# Where do I add the filter value to this function?

Tags: javascript, velo

I need some help with listing `ACTIVE` current Member orders:

```
export function button_click(event) {

    const urlId = getUrlId();

    if (wixUsers.currentUser.loggedIn) {
        // Check for active orders (!! HELP !!)
        orders.listCurrentMemberOrders()
            .then((ordersList) => {
                if (ordersList.length > 0) {
                    // Member has active orders
                    const firstOrderStatus = ordersList[0].status;
                    wixLocation.to(`/profil/kontakt/${urlId}`);
                } else {
                    // Member has no orders
                    wixLocation.to(`/abonnementer`);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    } else { 

// rest of my code
```

Currently, this code checks if there are ANY orders - even cancelled and ended orders.

The API tells me that I should be able to `filter` orders by `'ACTIVE'`

Link to API: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-pricing-plans-frontend/orders/listcurrentmemberorders

Example from the API reference:

```
import { orders } from 'wix-pricing-plans-frontend'; 


/* Sample filters object: 
 * {
 *   'orderStatuses': ['PAUSED', 'CANCELED']
 * }
 */

/* Sample sorting object: 
 * {
 *   'fieldName': '_createdDate',
 *   'order': 'DESC'
 * }
 */

/* Sample paging object: 
 * {
 *   'limit': 2
 * }
 */

$w('#listMyOrdersButton').onClick((event) => {
  orders.listCurrentMemberOrders(filters, sorting, paging)
    .then((ordersList) => {
      const firstOrderId = ordersList[0]._id;
      const firstCreatedDate = ordersList[0]._createdDate;
  
      console.log('Your list of filtered and sorted orders:', ordersList);
      return ordersList;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
});
```

I just can't get it to work -- the example provided doesn't help me, and adding the word 'ACTIVE' various places doesn't solve it for me.

So, does anyone know how do I implement the `filter` `'ACTIVE'` to the code?

Thanks!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've just updated my question with the example from the API reference. I don't understand where I should add `'ACTIVE'` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we follow the instructions in the documentation, the filter argument is expected to be an object with one or more properties that each has an array of strings as value. So it should work like this:

```
orders.listCurrentMemberOrders({ orderStatuses: ['ACTIVE'] })
```

If you also want to include another status, like maybe PAUSED, then just add it to the array:

```
orders.listCurrentMemberOrders({ orderStatuses: ['ACTIVE', 'PAUSED'] })
```

Comment: I get this error: " Type 'string[]' has no properties in common with type 'CurrentMemberFilterOptions'. "

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. Argument should be an object with property "orderStatuses". See update.

Comment: Thank you! My site was running live with customers and I had to get to this solution quickly. I really appreciate your help. It worked! (My reputation is still too low to give you an upvote - but really, thanks a lot!)